# Index Analysis and Tuning tool for PostgreSQL, MySQL, and Oracle?

Tags: database, mysql, postgresql, performance-analysis, oracle-database

I have used [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) to perform index tuning and index analysis with great success on SQL Server and Azure SQL Database.

What are some of the better equivalent tools to consider for other DBEs such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, and Oracle?

**Context:** We're performing a "Database Engine Comparison" analysis to compare when we might use a non-SQL Server option. This analysis includes not just the cost of hosting/running the DBE but also maintenance, development, and tooling. While there are some other tools that we have questions about (backup automation, version control, etc.), I'm currently tackling the index tuning portion of our analysis.

I don't care what OS it runs on. I do not currently have any price requirements until I have an idea what the options are. The tool I am currently using (SentryOne Plan Explorer) only works with SQL Server, thus I am specifically lacking compatibility with PostgreSQL, MySQL, and Oracle. I need it to assist me in performing index tuning and index analysis.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.For example: what features do you need? What OS should it run on? What about the price? What do you miss in the tool you already successfully used?

Comment: I don't care what OS it runs on. I do not currently have any price requirements until I have an idea what the options are. The tool I am currently using (SentryOne Plan Explorer) only works with SQL Server, thus I am specifically lacking compatibility with PostgreSQL, MySQL, and Oracle. I need it to assist me in performing index tuning and index analysis. This was all stated in the OP. What else do you want to know? I'm willing to conform to what's industry-standard for these DBEs, I just don't know what that standard is.

Comment: It's not me wanting to know – it's just improving your chances for matching answers. I've integrated the relevant part with your question as comments are rather "temporary elements". Good luck!